# V1 signed Release APK is not working in Android Q beta, but Works with V2 Signed APK

Tags: android

For some reasons we can't use V2 Signed Released APK, we need to use V1 Signed APK. But with Android Q(Beta),after installing APK we are unable to launch app itself.

We will not get any logs to debug what went wrong.

Please let me know, how to solve this issue with Android Q.

Answer (score 0):

V2 Signed or not signed APK will be generated and should run with out any issue.

Clean Project and Rebuild project(Tools>build Clean Project) and check if your device or emulator already have App with same package name. If so Uninstall old apk and try installing newly generated apk.

Use **same key**(key.jks) and **password** file that you created at first. Using different may cause error or Apk may not generate.

in Help>Show log in Explorer will show log if there is any error. Upload Log file if above doesn't help

Comment: Issue is not with Installing the App. As i mention above, we are able to install the app but unable to launch it with Android Q Beta version which was working for other Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Android Q Beta-5 and is solved with Beta-6. 
For Details, Please go through below Android bug tracker,
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139040934